# Error: Unknown custom element (only for some components)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I get the following error when trying to import *ForgotPassword.vue* inside *Login.vue*. *Tooltip.vue* can be imported with no error though? Can't figure out what I'm doing differently. I have had similar problems before. Sometimes I get this error randomly (it works on and off):

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <forgot-password> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Login> at src/components/register/Login.vue
       <Register> at src/views/Register.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Login.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div id="login">
    <tooltip />
    <forgot-password />
  </div>
</template>
```

```
import {
  Tooltip,
  ForgotPassword
} from '@/components'

export default {
  components: {
    Tooltip,
    ForgotPassword
  }
}
```

ForgotPassword.vue (not using props name but have tried that too. Didn't need it for other similar components that work):

```html
<template>
  <div id="forgot-password">
    ouch..
  </div>
</template>
```

components/index.js (for grouped imports):

```
import Tooltip from './Tooltip.vue'
import ForgotPassword from './ForgotPassword.vue'

export {
  Tooltip,
  ForgotPassword
}
```

Comment: Try using the following in your components block:

'forgot-password': ForgotPassword

Comment: @zer0kompression It is not a solution that I prefer, but it does work so thanks! Do you know why I have to do like this component and why not for some 
other components?

Comment: It probably has to do with the way the element name gets translated. Try using <forgotpassword /> and see if it works.

Comment: I just got the same error again @zer0kompression, with your suggested fix (even though it worked just awhile ago). This is so confusing to me.. I removed your suggested solution and it work again. It is as if I have to force re-register the component once in a while to get it to work?

Comment: Perhaps there is a confusion between the ForgotPassword component (<forgot-password>) and the div ID that you're defining (div id='forgot-password') within the component. Try changing the ID to something else and test.

Comment: @zer0kompression sadly doesn't make any difference. It might be by chance but in my index.js I am importing/exporting 22 components. I have started to get this problem lately so I thought maybe it's because it's too many components? So I moved the import of ForgetPassword from row 22 to 1, and after that it works. I'm guessing at least the problem has to do with the index.js import/export file.

Answer (score 0):

You're exporting **ForgetPassword** and importing **ForgotPassword**. Change one of them

Comment: So sorry, that was actually just a typo from my end.. It's ForgotPassword everywhere in the real code.